# RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1' discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

He creado un bot de precios para discord (Se pone en el estado del bot el precio actual de una cripto dada), y quiero hacer hilos para que en cada bot se ejecute una cripto diferente todo al mismo tiempo, pero me salta el siguiente error y ni idea.
He estado buscando y buscando y no encuentro como solucionarlo, además es simple el código no tiene nada, y los hilos están bien lanzados.
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2' este es el error que se da en todos los hilos, he adjuntado también una captura de pantalla para que se pueda ver al completo.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ws8p.png)

```
def main(TOKEN, cripto):
    cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
    
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

    
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready(): #Enciende el bot
        print('Logged in as')
        print(bot.user.name)
        print(bot.user.id)
        print('------')
        bot.loop.create_task(actualizarEstado_task(cripto)) #Para ejecutar tarea en segundo plano, mientras todo lo demas del bot se sigue ejecutando normal sin quedarse pillados en la funcion task
        print('------------ TASK LANZADA ------------')
        
    
    async def actualizarEstado_task(cripto):
        while True:

            moneda='usd'

            if moneda=='usd':
                simboloMoneda='$'
            elif moneda=='eur':
                simboloMoneda='€'

            dictCriptos=cg.get_price(ids=['bitcoin','ethereum','solana'], vs_currencies=moneda)
            
            if cripto=='BTC':
                dictBitcoin=dictCriptos['bitcoin']
                BitcoinValor=dictBitcoin['usd']
                estadoBot='BTC:  ' +str(BitcoinValor) + " "+simboloMoneda + " ⚡"
            elif cripto=='ETH':
                dictethereum=dictCriptos['ethereum']
                ethereumValor=dictethereum['usd']
                estadoBot="ETH: " +str(ethereumValor) + " " +simboloMoneda + " ⚡"
            
            else:
                dictsolana=dictCriptos['solana']
                solanaValor=dictsolana['usd'] 
                estadoBot="SOL: " +str(solanaValor) + " "+ simboloMoneda +" ⚡"
        
            print("************ PRECIOS ACTUALIZADOS ************")
            await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=estadoBot))
            print(estadoBot)
            await asyncio.sleep(600)
            print("************ PRECIOS ACTUALIZADOS ************")
            await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=estadoBot))
            print(estadoBot)
            await asyncio.sleep(600)

    

    bot.run(TOKEN)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    numberBots=3
    #1. Bitcoin, 2.ETH, 3. sol
    TOKEN=['1','2','3']
    CRIPTO=['BTC','ETH','SOL']


    for i in range(numberBots):
        token=TOKEN[i]
        cripto= CRIPTO[i]       
        thread=threading.Thread(target=main,args=(token,cripto))
        thread.start()
```

Comment: No se la solución, pero quizá no necesites usar multiples tareas. No puedo probarlo ahora (en unas 6 horas podría darte una respuesta detallada), pero podrías usar el poder de lo asincronico para iniciar varios bots al mismo tiempo: el método [start](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.start). Nunca lo usé, pero podría ser util en este caso.

Comment: @DanteS. Hola muchas gracias por responder, si pudieras darme una respuesta un poco más detallada como dijiste antes, esque ahora mismo no se usar muy bien lo asincrono.

Answer (score 0):

De la siguiente manera actualizarías como se debe el estado de uno de los bots:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=discord.Intents.default())
TOKEN = "tu token"

def actualizar_precios():
    # Obten el valor de la cripto
    return "estado" # el estado que quieres poner al bot

@tasks.loop(seconds = 600) # se ejecutará esta función cada 600 segundos
async def actualizar_estado():
    estado = actualizar_precios()
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=estado))

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    actualizar_estado.start()    
    print("Conectado")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Suponiendo que los hilos están bien lanzados como dices, deberías ser capaz de obtener una versión funcional para 3 bots añadiendo el `if __name__ == '__main__': ...` que pasaste e indicando los argumentos necesarios (token y cripto relacionados al bot) en las funciones del código que pasé.

A las malas puedes lanzar los bots por separado, creando 3 programas independientes, cada uno de ellos ejecutando un bot distino.

Referencias:

- [tasks.loop()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#discord.ext.tasks.loop)
- [tasks.Loop.start()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.start)